# App Configuration Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have create a SharePoint WebPart as well as a CommandBar-Extension using SPFx. I used the yeoman generator to schaffold the application and finally created a sppkg-file I can deploy to my app-catalog.

However: I would need some kind of configuration for the WebPart and the Extension. If it would only be the WebPart I could work with the WebPart property pane, but for the Commandbar-Extension this doesn't work.

Is there any way to have some kind of configuration-page/setup-page where I could store some value for e.g. as a property (in the site property-bag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ClientSideComponentProperties` in SPFx extensions.

`ClientSideComponentProperties` can be used to provide instance specific configurations in `elements.xml` file during solution development.

**Documentation**: [Add a ListView Command Set to a solution package for deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#Add-a-ListView-Command-Set-to-a-solution-package-for-deployment)

---

If you want to change the values of `ClientSideComponentProperties` after deployment, you can use APIs call for that. Check below link for the same:

[How does one pass parameters to SharePoint Framework Extensions in practice?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227137/how-does-one-pass-parameters-to-sharepoint-framework-extensions-in-practice)

---

**Update**:

Here's one SPFx sample developed by community members which allow you to update properties of SPFx application customizer: [Edit Application Customizers](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-edit-applicationcustomizer)

[image]

Comment: Thx. I think I'll go this way and create an "amin webpart" that will allow to configure those properties. Although I would have loved a way that would not involve so much custom code.